# Styling to recreate the amazon filter?

Tags: css, styles, uisearchbar

I want a similar search filter for an application. I have a dropdown list with input box plus go button? Can anyone recreate the css for it?

[image]

Comment: Right click > Inspect element; learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty simple to do with [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/). Learn it!

jsfiddle: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/Fn5DR/5/)

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-inverse" type="button">Go!</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But the fiddle is not showing accurate result...
Please revert. I too am in need of the same.

Comment: The external references to Bootstrap were bad, I fixed them, the fiddle should be working again.